# How to trace the route of a host using Java?

Tags: java, traceroute

In Windows, using the `tracert <host>` command gives us the intermediate ip addresses, How to do this in Java,  other than using `Runtime` class ?

Comment: You can't. `traceroute` does it with the ICMP protocol, which isn't accessible in standard Java. You would have to use one of the numerous JPcap implementations, wrappers over `libpcap`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627706/how-to-to-icmps-and-traceroutes-in-java

Comment: Or you can call `tracert` or `traceroute` from Java to get it to do the hard work.