# How to implement trace-routes in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, ping, traceroute

Given the fact that Android doesn't include a trace-route command, how can I implement the network utility within my app? I know a trace-route is just ping until pinging every hop/router on the way - but how can I do this grammatically? I tried searching for libraries on GitHub and Maven repositories but no luck of anything I can use. I don't mind implementing it myself. I hope I don't have to do this from scratch like crafting a packet and using a socket to connect to every router on the way. Another question would be how to obtain the IP of every router to the destination in Java?

Comment: Look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627706/how-to-icmps-and-traceroutes-in-java

Comment: that's for windows and linux, I want to implement in android... in that post the code access the command through the os. android os doesn't have that option.. thanks

Comment: I've seen plenty of android apps developing this traceroute but can't figure out how they did it

Comment: So did you find this post: [Traceroute on android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4203374/295004) and the github project listed as an answer was/wasn't useful? (I see command line 'ping' command in source code which give me doubt)